# How to disable drag and drop of text within the textarea?

Tags: html, user-interface, drag-and-drop, textarea

I am working on UI Design, where I need to use Html textarea object.  The sample code is:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="60" spellcheck="false" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Verdana;">
Abc
Xyz
Mnp
Pqr
</textarea>
```

I don't want to disable the textarea, since there are some cross-browser issues.  If I point on 'y' in 'xyz' and drag it after text 'Mnp', it will be shifted as 'Mnpyz'.  I want to avoid this drag and drop feature of text within the text area.

Comment: Use `ondrop="return false;"` for textarea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you want the users not change the contents of `textarea`, you can use `readonly` attribute.

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="60" spellcheck="false" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Verdana;"
    readonly="readonly">
Abc
Xyz
Mnp
Pqr
</textarea>
```